# problem with running files in intellije idea,itsApparently the problem was caused by windows security

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, windows-security

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4X4m.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ndqq.png)
Windows Defender might impact performance
Exclude IDE and project directories from antivirus scans:
C:\Users\shahrokh\IdeaProjects\untitled1
C:\Users\shahrokh\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.2
C:\Users\shahrokh.gradle
Alternatively, add the IDE process as an exclusion.

i search it in the special site of intellij idea ,and see it:

If you prefer to perform the necessary configuration manually, you can do so by following these steps:

```
Click the Start button
Type “Windows Security”
Click on “Virus and threat protection”
Click on “Manage settings” under “Virus & threat protection settings”
Scroll down if needed, and then click on “Add or remove exclusions”
For every folder shown in the notification, press the + button, select “Folder” from the menu, and select the folder.
```

but when i search Windows Security my system show me windows defender ,there arent these setting

In addition, I changed my anti-virus settings so as not to interfere with the intellij idea process. But again, the problem was not solved.
i use kaspersky protection
please help me

Comment: You need to exclude folders/processes from your antivirus, IDE documentation cannot cover all possible scenarios. Refer to Kaspersky documentation for the details how to do it. I also checked that these settings are available in the current Windows version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about anything. IntelliJ will continue to function as it is intended to and will get the work done. I also get some messages like this sometimes and just ignore them. Again there's no major impact on the performance. Hope that I was able to help.

Comment: thank you ! The first few days were not a problem. But since yesterday, it compiles my codes incomplete! Do not run at all. Because of this I use online compilers and this is harassed

Comment: Oh. Could you please elaborate on that a bit? Your code is not compiling completely?

Comment: I am a newcomer and I think this happened because some part of my description went into the code but... please read the whole question in a single text

Comment: when i want to run my code...At the bottom of the page there is a blue bar that is half full. At the top is written build and below it is written  preforming incremental compilatio.... My main problem is that my code does not run, my English is not very good, I do not know if I can get what I mean or not, but I do not know what to say anymore

Comment: Hey @shahin, do you mind sending a picture of what that looks like via imgur.com? I will try to help you out as much as I can.

Comment: thank you! michael the problem is solved i uninstall it then install it again

Answer (score 0):

i uninstall my intellij idea then install it again and it solved